# Zend Render adding extra text to the div

Tags: php, zend-framework

when using render or layout()->content, in case the .phtml file is saved as UTF-8, Zend is adding extra string inside the DIV forcing the layout to show one line below the expected.

```
<div class="content">
   <?php echo $this->layout()->content ?>
<!-- end .content --></div>
<div class="sidebar2">
   <?php echo $this->render('/scripts/bar.phtm'); ?>
<!-- end .sidebar2 --></div>
```

given that bar.phtml is

```
<div class="someclass">
  <p>Any foreing accentuated text like 'não'</p>
</div>
```

The result is that the special chars appears as a Question Mark if the file is in another codepage than UTF-8. If in UTF-8 the result will be

UTF-8

```
<div class="someclass">"    "
  <p>Any foreing accentuated text like 'não'</p>
</div>
```

Other charset

```
<div class="someclass">
  <p>Any foreing accentuated text like 'n?o'</p>
</div>
```

That extra string forces flow my layout no line below the original position and its added by the result of calling render or layout.

Anyone knows how to get it right?

Comment: You're not closing your content or sidebar divs. (I don't think fixing that would resolve your problem, but you should anyway)

Comment: Have you checked that Byte Order Mark (BOM) is not prepended to your phtml file when saving in UTF-8?

Comment: @GordonM, where is it not closed? I didn't got your point. Theres an open and clode div on it.

Comment: @bububaba, true. It says byte order mark is BOM.

Comment: @bububaba, please answer it so I can give you the credits!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked that Byte Order Mark (BOM) is not prepended to your phtml file when saving in UTF-8?

Comment: Damn! You beat me to it. I had exactly the same thought. :-)

Comment: Well, that was actually a few days ago ;) I already forgot about this question :P

Comment: Yeah but I didn't see it until your answer pushed it to the homepage.